# Selenium firefox 21 cannot log.debug when recording, nothing showing up when logging in javascript

Tags: javascript, logging, selenium, selenium-ide

I would love to see things on the console but nothing shows up.

This is logging in javascript.

I have instead used the echo command and that helps for a while but I really need to be able to log and see what I log.

I've tried creating a new logger object even.

This may in fact not be a selenium issue but how firefox is set up.

Also, Logging does work when I am playing back, it is not working when I am recording.

I do have firebug and firepath installed and I still don't see anything unless I don't now where to look.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to the version of Firefox.

The only way to see logging to during recording is to first play something back. Therefore, if you open the Selenium window and immediately start recording commands, logging for that activity is lost until at least one command is played back. E.g., record a command, then double click it, (even if that results in an error), then continue recording. Now you will see logging for subsequent recording.

This is probably the single most irritating deficiency with the Selenium IDE.

Comment: I have tried doing what you described and I still can't see the logging. Have you tried this recently and can you still view the logging while recording?